# Grunt compile external JS into inline HTML

Tags: javascript, html, gruntjs

Is it possible to take code from an external JS file, then paste it inline into script tags (in index.html), once the application is built?

For example, both files below are intended to be identical but I'd like the JS to be implemented externally in the src/dir and inline within the build/dir:

**src**/index.html

```
<head>
  <script src="long/minified/code.js"></script>
</head>
```

**build**/index.html

```
<head>
  <script>
    // long... minified code to be added inline here
  </script>
</head>
```

long/minified/code.js

```
(function(){var this,isSomeLong='minifiedCode';})();
```

Gruntfile.js

```
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        dist: {
            src: [
                'long/minified/code.js',

                  ],
            dest: 'build/index.html',
         }
});
```

It's possible I'm completely off and need something like [grunt-include-source](https://github.com/jwvdiermen/grunt-include-source#usage-examples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`grunt-processhtml`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-processhtml) to easily inline your scrips:

HTML

```
<head>
<!-- build:js inline -->
<script src="long/minified/code.js"></script>
<!-- /build -->
</head>
```

Gruntfile task:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  processhtml: {
    dist: {
      files: {
        'build/index.html': ['src/index.html']
      }
    }
  }
});
```